# New PDO::query while fetching other query

Tags: php, pdo

There is a sample of old PHP code (not real code, just for understading of problem).

```
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT MILLIONS ROWS FROM TABLES");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        // other different queries (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) & other complex logic 
        $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT SOME DATA");
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2);
        $q3 = mysql_query("UPDATE SOME ROWS");
        $q4 = mysql_query("SELECT SOME OTHER DATA");
        // many other code, that works with DataBase and do many other things
        // ...
    }
```

This old code works fine.
But I need to move this code to PHP7 and PDO (instead of mysql_).
In the project about 3000 places of code like this.

I tryed to rewrite code like this:

```
    $pdo = new PDO('connection string');
    $q = $pdo->query("SELECT MILLIONS ROWS FROM TABLES");
    while($row = $q->fetch()) {
        // other different queries (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) & other complex logic 
        $q2 = $pdo->query("SELECT SOME DATA");
        $data = $q2->fetch();
        $q3 = $pdo->query("UPDATE SOME ROWS");
        $q4 = $pdo->query("SELECT SOME OTHER DATA");
        // many other code, that works with DataBase and do many other things
        // ...
    }
```

It does not work: the loop executes one time, though rows in a table a few million.
This is natural, because it is written in the manual:

> If you do not fetch all of the data in a result set before issuing your next call to PDO::query(), your call may fail. Call PDOStatement::closeCursor() to release the database resources associated with the PDOStatement object before issuing your next call to PDO::query().

I can rewrite the code using fetchAll, then it will work.

```
    $pdo = new PDO('connection string');
    $q = $pdo->query("SELECT MILLIONS ROWS FROM TABLES");
    $rows = $q->fetchAll();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
         // other different queries (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) & other complex logic 
        $q2 = $pdo->query("SELECT SOME DATA");
        $data = $q2->fetch();
        $q3 = $pdo->query("UPDATE SOME ROWS");
        $q4 = $pdo->query("SELECT SOME OTHER DATA");
        // many other code, that works with DataBase and do many other things
        // ...
    }
```

But this option does not suit me, because fetchAll eats all memory and the script fails.

Also, i can rewrite code like this:

```
    $pdo = new PDO('connection string');
    for($i=0; $<=10000; $i++) {
        $offset = $i * 1000;
        $q = $pdo->query("SELECT ROWS FROM TABLES LIMIT $offset, 1000");
        $rows = $q->fetchAll();
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            // other different queries (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) & other complex logic 
            $q2 = $pdo->query("SELECT SOME DATA");
            $data = $q2->fetch();
            $q3 = $pdo->query("UPDATE SOME ROWS");
            $q4 = $pdo->query("SELECT SOME OTHER DATA");
            // many other code, that works with DataBase and do many other things
            // ...
        }
    }
```

But this method does not suit me, because i have to rewrite a lot of code in the project and i don't want do this.

How to move this code to PDO? 
Is there other way to make PDO queries while fetching data by the first query ?

Comment: Use `PDOStatement` class objects.

Comment: Whet you *really* need is to learn SQL. All your code could be and should be replaced by a single SQL query followed by a fetch()/fetchAll() geting the actual results you need.

Comment: How do you make PDO::query() called statically?Is it a real code you are using?

Comment: of course, its not real code.

Comment: If it's not a real code, how do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put in in 1 query?

```
SELECT `Table2`.* FROM `Table2`
JOIN `Table1`
ON `Table1`.`id` = `Table2`.`id`
```

This will be more performant, and give the results you want.

Comment: i can's use JOINs, beacause in a loop more complex logic

Comment: I don't see a reason why you couldn't use joins. Worst-case you could also use a sub-query, but a join should work (even with complex queries).

Comment: @Rmk you always can use joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
$q = PDO::query("SELECT Table2.* FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table2.id=Table1.id");
while($data = $q->fetch()) {
    // some code here
}
```

Comment: i can's use JOINs, beacause in a loop more complex logic

Comment: Every separated query in the loop will require a lot of system resources and increase execution time. If you develope big-data app, you have to begin transfer business-logic yours app into database (or query). You should use joins for only one query (with some business-logic) for performance. If you show your app (parent-query + loop), maby we can advice you how to refactor it.